# Wordpress admin-post.php only working if role=admin, but need subscriber role to work too

Tags: php, wordpress

On a Wordpress website, I am using admin-post.php in a form (code below) on my website to trigger an action upon submitting the form, where I can process the $_POST items and set some cookies.  This works fine if I set my account role to admin, but does not work if I simply change the role to subscriber (I will need my subscribers to be able to submit this form).  As subscriber role, instead of running admin-post.php, it just redirects me to the website homepage, even though I am still logged in.  So it acts like admin-post.php is not executable as subscriber role, but I am not sure how to change this... maybe I need a some kind of .htaccess code in the wp-admin dir?  I am stumped... any ideas?

```
< form method='post' action='/wp-admin/admin-post.php'>

< input type='hidden' name='action' value='run_my_wp_action'   >
//Other form items removed

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Next' >
</form >
```

**PHP in my WP plugin**

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_run_my_wp_action', 'my_wp_action' );     
add_action( 'admin_post_input_run_my_wp_action', 'my_wp_action' );          

function my_wp_action() {   //code  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer your specific question, but this doesn't seem the right way to play with permissions. Have you considered making a separate form in your plugin that will allow any user role to submit it, but without the potential loopholes that the question implies?

Comment: I think I may need to.  Do you know if this is this intended operation (where subscriber role cannot access admin-posts.php?)

Answer (score 0):

Try with wp_ajax.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_wp_action', 'my_wp_action' );          
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_wp_action', 'my_wp_action' ); 

function my_wp_action() {   //code  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  A simple change of the hook to the ajax as above didn't work.  I still get redirected to the homepage, I think because the form is still referencing admin-post.php.  I tried a quick change of the form link to admin-ajax.php instead of admin-post.php, but still did not work.  I can try to make .js file then to make a Ajax call and set the cookies in there.  Really just looking for the simplest way to set cookies (as subscriber role) upon form submission, if you have other thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `admin_post_{action_name}` hook should work for all logged-in users (admin, editor, subscriber, etc.).
Most likely what's blocking the post request in your case is a third-party plugin. My first guess would be 'User Registration' or 'Paid Memberships pro' or a similar plugin that offers the option to `disable_dashboard_access` for certain user roles(subscribers). If that doesn't help try disabling all plugins / switching theme to default.